# PHP Array Case Statement Check

Tags: php

I have a variable that may either be a string of the group id or an array of many group id's. Is there wa way to shorten a check to see if they belong to a group.

```
if(is_array($groups)){
    /* Check for multiple groups */
    $total = count($groups);
    $hasperm = false;
    while($total > 0){
        /* If account has a bad status dont login */
        switch($group[$total]){
            case 4:
                $errmsg_arr[] = array('type'=>'crucial','alert'=>'Alert!','msg'=>'Your account is not active, contact admin');
                failedAttempt($errmsg_arr);
                break;
            case 6:
                $errmsg_arr[] = array('type'=>'crucial','alert'=>'Alert!','msg'=>'Your account is banned, contact admin');
                failedAttempt($errmsg_arr);
                break;
            case 5:
                $errmsg_arr[] = array('type'=>'crucial','alert'=>'Alert!','msg'=>'Your account is scheduled for deletion, if you are reading this you may still have time to recover your account, Call 716-698-9236. $50 Reactivation fee required.');
                failedAttempt($errmsg_arr);
                break;
        }
        $total--;
    }
}else{
    /* If account has a bad status dont login */
    switch($groups){
        case 4:
            $errmsg_arr[] = array('type'=>'crucial','alert'=>'Alert!','msg'=>'Your account is not active, contact admin');
            failedAttempt($errmsg_arr);
            break;
        case 6:
            $errmsg_arr[] = array('type'=>'crucial','alert'=>'Alert!','msg'=>'Your account is banned, contact admin');
            failedAttempt($errmsg_arr);
            break;
        case 5:
            $errmsg_arr[] = array('type'=>'crucial','alert'=>'Alert!','msg'=>'Your account is scheduled for deletion, if you are reading this you may still have time to recover your account, Call 716-698-9236. $50 Reactivation fee required.');
            failedAttempt($errmsg_arr);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using a `while` loop rather than a `foreach` there? It took me a while to understand what it was for, which is a bad sign for future maintenance. The only thing I can see is that it will go through the array in reverse numeric order, although why that would be necessary I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not an array, create a one-element array containing the value. Then use the code you've already written for arrays.

```
if (!is_array($groups)) {
    $groups = array($groups);
}
// Now use the array code
```

Comment: agreed. @ldrrp, if your use is var AND array, you have to check which it is then serve things specific to both vars AND arrays. If you just use array everytime, then you just have one set of checks, is_array, are there any values/keys, etc.

Comment: You can also do `$groups = (array)$groups`, which will leave the variable untouched if it is already an array, produce a single-element array for any "scalar" value, and produce an empty array for `null`.